# Not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but can someone please help me understand the way the delete function is working here?

Tags: javascript

```js
function addExpense() {
    let itemName = document.getElementById('item').value;
    let priceOfItem = document.getElementById('price').value;

    let tr = document.createElement('tr');

    let td1 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    let td2 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
    let td3 = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

    td1.innerHTML = itemName;
    td2.innerHTML = priceOfItem;
    td3.innerHTML = '<input type="button" id="delete" value="delete" onclick="deleteExpense(this)">'

    document.getElementById('expense_table').appendChild(tr);
}


function deleteExpense(thing) {
    let deletion = thing.parentNode.parentNode;
    deletion.parentNode.removeChild(deletion);
}
```

Hey so my understanding is that, after I add the button to a cell element, I call the delete function and pass 'this' (it's own object) as an argument, then in the delete function itself I keep an object parameter which and use the parentNode property which points towards the row and then the table? Am I on the right track?

TLDR - I am not understanding how the below lines are functioning, tried looking it up but didn't find a proper answer

```
let deletion = thing.parentNode.parentNode;
deletion.parentNode.removeChild(deletion);
```

Comment: [How do I write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Write a title that summarizes the problem

Comment: `thing` is the button, `thing.parentNode` the `<td>`, `thing.parentNode.parentNode` the `<tr>`, `deletion.parentNode` is the `<tbody>` + [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

Comment: Select it's own second parent for deletion, then select 3rd parent and from it remove selected element

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @AndreasThanks for the reply, I got it now, I just failed to understand that 'thing' is the button which is why I was confused. Sorry for the poorly formatted question.

Answer (score 0):

thing is the button, thing.parentNode the , thing.parentNode.parentNode the , deletion.parentNode is the  + Node.removeChild() – Andreas 1 hour ago